# Great validation accuracy but terrible prediction

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I have got the following CNN:

```
import os

import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tqdm import tqdm

# Load the data
data_dir = PATH_DIR
x_train = []
y_train = []
total_files = 0
for subdir in os.listdir(data_dir):
    subdir_path = os.path.join(data_dir, subdir)
    if os.path.isdir(subdir_path):
        total_files += len([f for f in os.listdir(subdir_path) if f.endswith('.npy')])

with tqdm(total=total_files, unit='file') as pbar:
    for subdir in os.listdir(data_dir):
        subdir_path = os.path.join(data_dir, subdir)
        if os.path.isdir(subdir_path):
            for image_file in os.listdir(subdir_path):
                if image_file.endswith('.npy'):
                    image_path = os.path.join(subdir_path, image_file)
                    image = np.load(image_path)
                    x_train.append(image)
                    y_train.append(subdir)
                    pbar.update()
x_train = np.array(x_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)

# Preprocess the labels
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y_train = label_encoder.fit_transform(y_train)
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)

# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(57, 57, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)
model.save('GeneratedModels/units_model_np.h5')
```

And then the following function that is called within a loop about 15 times a second. Where image is a numpy array.

```
def guess_unit(image, classList):
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(MODEL_PATH)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    prediction = model.predict(image, verbose=0)
    index = np.argmax(prediction)
    # Return the predicted unit
    return classList[index]
```

The problem is that when i train the model the accuracy is very high (99,99976%) but when I am using the predict the output is terribily wrong, to the point it does not make any sense. Sometimes the image received will be the same but the predict will return 2 different things.

I have no idea what am I doing wrong. It's the first time I am tinkering with Neural Networks.

I have tried to use the model.predict with the images that it was trained on and it's always getting them right. Is just when it receives dynamic images that it's terribly wrong.
NOTE: I have 8 classes and it was trained using about 13000 images.

Answer (score 0):

Generally to get performance on your training data you have to split your data into training, testing and validation (which I see you haven't done). This can be done manually or done via adding `validation_split` into your `fit` function.

Without seeing any curves on how your loss and accuracy it's behaving it's difficult to make any suggestions. However it might be the case that your are underfitting or overfitting to your data (I would assume that your facing overfitting in your case). In case you are overfitting to your data, I would suggest you to add some regularization or change your model architecture as the one used might not be appropriate. Options that one could think of would be to add regularization via Dropout or adding regularization to your weights.